# How to grant access to certain users using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, permissions

I am having an issue with PHP, as I am trying to write a program that will redirect the user back to the previous page (membersOnly.php). Here is the code that isn't currently working for me.

```
$sess = $_SESSION['sess_username'];

if ($sess == "admin") {
    return;
} else {
     header("Location: membersOnly.php");
}
```

My attempt is to only allow the user "admin" into the admin.php page. This code is the first thing to run. The $_SESSION['sess_username'] variable is assigned in login.php with the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $_POST['user'];
header("Location: membersOnly.php");
```

Now I know I am correctly setting the session username, because in any page I choose, I can use echo $_SESSION['sess_username']; and it displays the username. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong when I try to send the user back to membersOnly.php if their username is not admin. Currently when I try to go to that page, it denies access to any user, including admin.

[EDIT: SOLVED]
I forgot to add session_start(); at the top of the page.

Comment: ok, it appears that you're calling `return;`, which most likely is just returning an empty page. Try changing it to `die('IM AN ADMIN');` and `die('IM NOT AN ADMIN');` to start with, and see what results you get.

Comment: no that's not it, but thanks for the pointer @Danbopes

Comment: What do you mean "that's not it"? What are you getting? Is it showing `IM AN ADMIN` or `IM NOT AN ADMIN`?

Comment: @Danbopes when I say thats not it, im saying thats not what the problem was. but when i change $sess == "admin" to $sess != "admin" it does display IM AN ADMIN, but none of the other content on the page. I know now that it is not understanding that "admin" is the session name but i cant figure out how to fix this.

Comment: I removed my comment about using error reporting; it was ignored (twice). Had you used that, it would have clearly thrown you that the session wasn't started and an undefined index notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danbopes is right, you are "returning" an empty page. You can simply do this. Now note that this code will not work unless the username "admin" is saved in the session.

```
$sess = $_SESSION['sess_username'];

if($sess !== 'admin'){
    header("Location: membersOnly.php");
    exit();
}

//ADMIN CONTENT
```

Comment: its just sending any user whatsoever back to membersOnly.php

Comment: Okay, try to echo the session "sess_username" on top of this code for now. Does it say admin in lowercase like in the code.

Comment: Ok I just found the answer. I forgot to put session_start(); on the top of the code. Thank you very much i realized this when i tried to echo it and it didnt echo anything. Thank you maam

Comment: @user3670816 The question I never ask anymore whether `session_start();` is loaded inside all files using sessions. 99 times out of a 100, OP's always say: *"Yes, it's loaded."*

Comment: I can't see why this answer should be accepted; it wasn't the return, it was missing `session_start();`. - The OP themselves should have posted one.